# Getting error with MiniProfiler: System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule does not implement IHttpHandlerFactory

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, webforms, mvc-mini-profiler

I'm using MiniProfiler to profile my ASP.NET 4 Webform application. In localhost it works fine, but when I deploy to IIS7 I receive the following error:

```
System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule does not implement IHttpHandlerFactory or IHttpHandler
```

This is the web.config lines that gives me the error

```
<system.webServer>
<handlers>
  <add name="MiniProfiler" path="mini-profiler-resources" verb="*" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
</handlers>
```

Do you have any idea what should I do in this situation?

Comment: I'm getting the same error exactly, but I'm running under IIS6

Comment: I do get the same error in Visual Studio Cassini server. No idea hw to fix it

Comment: Can you review your path to see if it has any dot (.). The following path won't work: http://localhost:<port>/MyApplication.Admin.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I ended up with using the following config. It might be overkill and not generally recommended, but I solved my problem

```
<module runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
```

Comment: @LDJ: Please make sure that your application path doesn't include "." character. For example localhost:1234/my-application.admin won't work

Answer (score 0):

```
 <handlers>
    <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0"/>
    <add  name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" />
  </handlers>
```

Comment: Would you like to add some commentary on your answer to explain which aspects resolve the original question?